# Repetitive database access or heavy parameters

Tags: php, database, connection, singleton

I need at some point to load(from a database) a set of texts(~10 000 texts) in a specific language of my website, to then display the website.

Should I be doing this each and every time I'm displaying an element, and this would require a lot of connection attempts?
Should I load the whole text once, and pass it as an argument then to the sub-elements that require it?

I was opting for a singleton class approach(load all once, then access specific element whenever needed), but it looks like this is not a good answer.

Comment: Are you getting this language from a database?

Comment: No context so unable to give a reasonable answer

Comment: Yes, I load the language from a database.

Answer (score 0):

if you specifically want to cache this 1 result, maybe make it a function with a static variable for caching?

```
string getEnglish() {
    static string ret = "";
    if (ret == "") { /*actually get the data from db, and put it in ret*/ }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I might have been unclear about what I was looking for. The issue is that i'm considering a huge set of texts